# Initial View Controller keeps reloading while user is interacting with other View Controllers in app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am new in iOS development. The project I'm working on has two View Controllers:

`VC1`:
- Has a simple button that says "`begin quiz`", with a segue to `VC2`. I created the segue in the storyboard editor, so `VC1` doesn't have a custom class. Pretty simple...almost like a splash page

`VC2`:
- Displays a question that is fetched from a plist and displayed in a `label` 
- User inputs an answer into an `textbox` and hits the `NEXT` button
- The `NEXT` event calls a method that 1)writes the answer to a SQLite DB, and 2) clears the `textbox`, and 3) loads the next question into the `label`

Problem Statement: The linking between `VC1` and `VC2` worked fine prior to adding any logic to commit the data to the database. Meaning, `VC1` would segue to `VC2`, and as a hit the `NEXT` button, a new question would load. However, after implementing logic to write to the database within the `NEXT` method, `VC1` would get reloaded. Note, that the values were committed to the DB. I've stepped through the code and I'm unable to decipher why `VC1` get's reloaded. There are not segues from `VC2` back to `VC1`.

Question: 
1. What would cause this behavior? 
2. Would the writing to the database logic cause this or was that an unrelated observation? 
3. In the storyboard, are their properties of the `VC2` I can set to ensure VC1 doesn't get reloaded. Perhaps I haven't specified something and `VC1` is getting loaded by default.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: add code of your next logic

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you using nib rather than using storybords. Nib will give you more control and you can easily navigate through screens.

Also try to check the next method you have written. You might be loading `VC1` again from the start. Once `VC1` is reloaded with fresh data, `VC2` will be automatically reloaded.